# Why does my filename cut-off when I copy a file from one directory to another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file, copy, console-application

I have this line of code that copies a file from one directory to another:

```
File.copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fileName), Path.Combine(destinationDir, fileName), true);
```

When I step through the code, all variables have the correct values and the full filename, but when I go view the file in the destination directory (`destinationDir`) the file is there with only part of the original file name...

The original file name is `New Employee Orientation - Benefits` and when it is copied over to the new destination is it `New Employee Orientation - Benefi`

I have another file that is similarly named and it cuts off at the same amount of characters (including white spaces).

Comment: By any chance, is the directory structure really long leading up to them? As in, on the order of 200+ characters long? EDIT: On second thought, this must be a subtle attempt of corporations [slashing employee benefits](http://instantrimshot.com/classic/?sound=rimshot).

Comment: Can you confirm that the strings returned by `Path.Combine` are full? @ChrisSinclair - Wahey! :D

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - Slashing benefits.... nice lol
But no, the directory is 64 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

Is `File.copy` your own function or a typo? Should be `File.Copy` if using .NET's Copy function.  If it's your own, need to see and walkthrough that code still.

Otherwise, character limit is 260 and a likely culprit. Move the `Path.Combine(string,string)` outside of `File.copy` and check the value and length.
See [Naming Files, Paths and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry.

I'll give what you suggested a try